# what does {a constant number} mean after a variable in julia?

Tags: variables, struct, julia

what does this {M} mean after the name of a variable?

I have seen something like this in the code:

Struct name{M}

I wanted to know what does this {M} do with our code?

Answer (score 2):

This allows to pass and manipulate numbers available at compile time rather than runtime. This can be used to dynamically construct data structures where later Julia can efficiently compile code for them.

Consider this struct:

```
Base.@kwdef struct AA{M}
    a::Array{Int, M} = rand(0:99, fill(3,M)...)
end
```

The dimensionality of the field `a` is stored together with the type information.
This could be used as:

```
julia> AA{1}()
AA{1}([70, 46, 20])

julia> AA{2}()
AA{2}([81 73 38; 65 50 77; 57 87 66])
```

Note that `M` is part of the type definition so knowing `M` the compiler knows the types of the underlying fields:

```
julia> fieldtypes(AA{1})
(Vector{Int64},)

julia> fieldtypes(AA{2})
(Matrix{Int64},)

julia> fieldtypes(AA{3})
(Array{Int64, 3},)
```

This behavior is particularly useful when combined with macros (programs transforming code at the compile time). While macros obviously cannot access values in the variables, they could make a great use from numeric parameters type such as `M`.
A great example of application would be https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl when knowing apriori the vector/array size can lead to a far more efficient machine code.

Answer (score 1):

In Julia, curly braces (`{}`) are used to parameterize a variable or type with a specific value or type. For example, a variable named `x{3}` is parameterized with the value 3, and `Struct name{M}` indicates that the name struct is parameterized with the type M.